# Fastest way to link words in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, string, token, stringtokenizer

I have a sentence in a simple PHP string:

```
$myString = "This is a test.";
```

I want an array that contains all possible connections between two words, or two groups of words, as follows (whitespace as a delimiter):

```
$myArray = [
    ["This", "is"],
    ["This", "is a"],
    ["This", "is a test."],
    ["This is", "a"],
    ["This is", "a test."],
    ["This is a", "test."],
    ["is", "a"],
    ["is", "a test."],
    ["is a", "test."],
    ["a", "test."]
];
```

It must run as fast as possible, hopefully in a single scan of the input string.

EDIT:

Here's what I've got so far, using a recursive function:

```
/**
 * @param string $string
 * @return string[]
 */
private function split($string)
{
    $whitespace = strpos($string, ' ');
    if (false === $whitespace) {
        return;
    }
    $segment = substr($string, 0, $whitespace);
    $string = substr($string, $whitespace + 1);
    $this->link($segment, $string);
    $this->split($string);
}

/**
 * @param string $segment
 * @param string $string
 */
private function link($segment, $string)
{
    $this->links[] = [$segment, $string];
}
```

Then I call `$this->split('this is a test');`
and obtain:

```
var_dump($this->links);
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => This
        [1] => is a test.
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => is
        [1] => a test.
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => test.
    )

)
```

I was about to walk the $links array backward with each call of the link() method, but the computational cost on a large document would be prohibitive.

Comment: 1. What have you tried so far? We won't write your code 2. *It must run as fast* There are many possible connections if you only have like 9 words!

Comment: Best to look at [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/explode) or [`strtok()`](http://www.php.net/strtok).

Comment: Absolutely @Rizier123, there are exponentially many connections. It's a great way to milk a small amount of data for all its worth. However, I can't seem to find a solution that doesn't involve nested loops. I'm melting my brain trying to find a way to accomplish this in a single pass.

Comment: Simple but important question: *why*? Why does it absolutely have to run as fast as possible? This doesn't seem like a real world requirement, ever.